large file in vs-code come problem folding and unfolding
I am facing an issue in VS Code with files that contain more than 3000 lines of code. Whenever my JavaScript file exceeds 3000 lines, all of my functions automatically unfold, even though I have set up the editor to automatically fold and format the code when I save the file.
The problem is that the unfolding of functions only happens when the file has over 3000 lines; if the file has fewer lines, the code remains folded as expected. I don't want to disable the auto-formatting upon save because I rely on that feature.
Is there any way to prevent the automatic unfolding of the code when the file has more than 3000 lines, while still maintaining the auto-formatting functionality on save?
I would prefer not to install any extensions or change the settings related to the auto-formatting (such as turning it off). Any help would be greatly appreciated!
What I have tried: I have tried disabling the "format on save" option and installing extensions for folding and unfolding code, but I don't want to disable the "format on save" feature, nor do I want to use any extensions for folding and unfolding.
What I am expecting: I want to maintain the "format on save" functionality and avoid using extensions, but I also need to prevent the code from automatically unfolding when the file exceeds 3000 lines.
Can anyone help me resolve this issue without changing the "format on save" setting or relying on extensions?

Not sure how to answer this but vscode can only do so much, it's not an actual IDE, if you are viewing files with 3000+ lines of code on a daily basis then you're better off switching to a proper IDE  instead like webstorm, eclipse etc

I would ask the developers: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues
